# What’s an example of a Monad which is an Alternative but not a MonadPlus?

Tags: haskell, monads, applicative, alternative-functor, monadplus

In [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10168111/237428) to the question [“Distinction between typeclasses `MonadPlus`, `Alternative`, and `Monoid`?”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10167879/237428), Edward Kmett says that

> Moreover, even if `Applicative` was a superclass of `Monad`, you’d wind up needing the `MonadPlus` class anyways, because obeying
>
> ```
> empty <*> m = empty
> ```
>
> isn’t strictly enough to prove that
>
> ```
> empty >>= f = empty
> ```
>
> So claiming that something is a `MonadPlus` is stronger than claiming it is `Alternative`.

It’s clear that any applicative functor which is *not* a monad is automatically an example of an `Alternative` which is not a `MonadPlus`, but Edward Kmett’s answer implies that there exists a *monad* which is an `Alternative` but not a `MonadPlus`: its `empty` and `<|>` would satisfy the `Alternative` laws,<sup>1</sup> but not the `MonadPlus` laws.<sup>2</sup>  I can’t come up with an example of this by myself; does anybody know of one?

---

<sup>1</sup> I wasn’t able to find a canonical reference for a set of `Alternative` laws, but I lay out what I believe them to be roughly halfway through [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081604/237428) to the question [“Confused by the meaning of the `Alternative` type class and its relationship to other type classes”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13080606/237428) (search for the phrase “right distributivity”).  The four laws I believe ought to hold are:

1. **Right distributivity (of `<*>`):**  `(f <|> g) <*> a = (f <*> a) <|> (g <*> a)`
2. **Right absorption (for `<*>`):**  `empty <*> a = empty`
3. **Left distributivity (of `fmap`):**  `f <$> (a <|> b) = (f <$> a) <|> (f <$> b)`
4. **Left absorption (for `fmap`):**  `f <$> empty = empty`

I’d also happily accept being given a more useful set of `Alternative` laws.

<sup>2</sup> I know that [there’s some ambiguity about what the `MonadPlus` laws are](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus); I’m happy with an answer that uses left distribution or left catch, although I would weakly prefer the former.

Comment: I always have believed that the only laws for Alternative and MonadPlus are the monoid laws.  Or, more specifically, I believe that there should be type-classes that encompass only the monoid laws, and any additional laws should be assigned to sub-classes.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez In practice this sort of thing happens a lot anyway. In my answer I show that an instance of MonadPlus from base doesn't satisfy these laws.

Comment: AndrewC: Of course it should say that.  It's always said that.  We have always been at war with Eastasia.  (Thanks, I went back and fixed my answer to the other question, too.)

Comment: Oh, I've just realised (having read @PetrPudlák's comment) - I think we should add associativity for <|>, specifically, (a <|> b) <|> c = a <|> (b <|> c).

Comment: @AndrewC: I was thinking of these as the additional non-monoid laws, since the only things the docs say is that `Alternative` is ["a monoid on applicative functors."](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative)  That's clear in the original context, but you're right, I probably should have been more explicit.

Comment: Of course. I realise now I'd misread absorbtion as identity anyway. My mistake. Too early in the day to think clearly, clearly.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The clue to your answer is in the [HaskellWiki about MonadPlus you linked to](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus):

> Which rules? Martin & Gibbons choose Monoid, Left Zero, and Left Distribution. This makes `[]` a MonadPlus, but not `Maybe` or `IO`.

So according to your favoured choice, `Maybe` isn't a MonadPlus (although there's an instance, it doesn't satisfy left distribution). Let's prove it satisfies Alternative.

### `Maybe` is an Alternative

1. **Right distributivity (of `<*>`):** `(f <|> g) <*> a = (f <*> a) <|> (g <*> a)`

Case 1: `f=Nothing`:

```
(Nothing <|> g) <*> a =                    (g) <*> a  -- left identity <|>
                      = Nothing         <|> (g <*> a) -- left identity <|>
                      = (Nothing <*> a) <|> (g <*> a) -- left failure <*>
```

Case 2: `a=Nothing`:

```
(f <|> g) <*> Nothing = Nothing                             -- right failure <*>
                      = Nothing <|> Nothing                 -- left identity <|>
                      = (f <*> Nothing) <|> (g <*> Nothing) -- right failure <*>
```

Case 3: `f=Just h, a = Just x`

```
(Just h <|> g) <*> Just x = Just h <*> Just x                      -- left bias <|>
                          = Just (h x)                             -- success <*>
                          = Just (h x) <|> (g <*> Just x)          -- left bias <|>
                          = (Just h <*> Just x) <|> (g <*> Just x) -- success <*>
```

1. **Right absorption (for `<*>`):** `empty <*> a = empty`

That's easy, because

```
Nothing <*> a = Nothing    -- left failure <*>
```

1. **Left distributivity (of `fmap`):** `f <$> (a <|> b) = (f <$> a) <|> (f <$> b)`

Case 1: `a = Nothing`

```
f <$> (Nothing <|> b) = f <$> b                        -- left identity <|>
                 = Nothing <|> (f <$> b)          -- left identity <|>
                 = (f <$> Nothing) <|> (f <$> b)  -- failure <$>
```

Case 2: `a = Just x`

```
f <$> (Just x <|> b) = f <$> Just x                 -- left bias <|>
                     = Just (f x)                   -- success <$>
                     = Just (f x) <|> (f <$> b)     -- left bias <|>
                     = (f <$> Just x) <|> (f <$> b) -- success <$>
```

1. **Left absorption (for `fmap`):** `f <$> empty = empty`

Another easy one:

```
f <$> Nothing = Nothing   -- failure <$>
```

### `Maybe` isn't a MonadPlus

Let's prove the assertion that `Maybe` isn't a MonadPlus: We need to show that `mplus a b >>= k = mplus (a >>= k) (b >>= k)` doesn't always hold. The trick is, as ever, to use some binding to sneak very different values out:

```
a = Just False
b = Just True

k True = Just "Made it!"
k False = Nothing
```

Now

```
mplus (Just False) (Just True) >>= k = Just False >>= k
                                     = k False
                                     = Nothing
```

here I've used bind `(>>=)` to snatch failure (`Nothing`) from the jaws of victory because `Just False` looked like success.

```
mplus (Just False >>= k) (Just True >>= k) = mplus (k False) (k True)
                                           = mplus Nothing (Just "Made it!")
                                           = Just "Made it!"
```

Here the failure (`k False`) was calculated early, so got ignored and we `"Made it!"`.

So, `mplus a b >>= k = Nothing` but `mplus (a >>= k) (b >>= k) = Just "Made it!"`.

You can look at this as me using `>>=` to break the left-bias of `mplus` for `Maybe`.

### Validity of my proofs:

Just in case you felt I hadn't done enough tedious deriving, I'll prove the identities I used:

Firstly

```
Nothing <|> c = c      -- left identity <|>
Just d <|> c = Just d  -- left bias <|>
```

which come from the instance declaration

```
instance Alternative Maybe where
    empty = Nothing
    Nothing <|> r = r
    l       <|> _ = l
```

Secondly

```
f <$> Nothing = Nothing    -- failure <$>
f <$> Just x = Just (f x)  -- success <$>
```

which just come from `(<$>) = fmap` and

```
instance  Functor Maybe  where
    fmap _ Nothing       = Nothing
    fmap f (Just a)      = Just (f a)
```

Thirdly, the other three take a bit more work:

```
Nothing <*> c = Nothing        -- left failure <*>
c <*> Nothing = Nothing        -- right failure <*>
Just f <*> Just x = Just (f x) -- success <*>
```

Which comes from the definitions

```
instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = return
    (<*>) = ap

ap :: (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
ap =  liftM2 id

liftM2  :: (Monad m) => (a1 -> a2 -> r) -> m a1 -> m a2 -> m r
liftM2 f m1 m2          = do { x1 <- m1; x2 <- m2; return (f x1 x2) }

instance  Monad Maybe  where
    (Just x) >>= k      = k x
    Nothing  >>= _      = Nothing
    return              = Just
```

so

```
mf <*> mx = ap mf mx
          = liftM2 id mf mx
          = do { f <- mf; x <- mx; return (id f x) }
          = do { f <- mf; x <- mx; return (f x) }
          = do { f <- mf; x <- mx; Just (f x) }
          = mf >>= \f ->
            mx >>= \x ->
            Just (f x)
```

so if `mf` or `mx` are Nothing, the result is also `Nothing`, whereas if `mf = Just f` and `mx = Just x`, the result is `Just (f x)`

Comment: (Also I could quite easily make a version of `Maybe` with right bias that would satisfy neither left catch nor left distribution, so wouldn't be a MonadPlus by any definition, but which will satisfy Alternative.)

Comment: I wonder, would it be possible to prove that anything that is a `MonadPlus` in one sense (Monoid, Left Zero, and Left Distribution) or another (Monoid, Left Zero, and Left Catch) is already an `Alternative`? This would give a very general answer to the original question.

Comment: @PetrPudlák I've looked into it and your question has (I believe) an interesting answer. Do you fancy asking it as a question? I don't think it fits into either this answer or my answer to the other question (in which I took a practical approach, hopefully complementing Antal's excellent tour of the theory). (I have a truly marvelous* answer to your question, which this margin** is too narrow*** to contain.) *OK, perhaps not marvelous. **comment box. ***character-limited.

Comment: I did here: [What are the relations between Alternative, MonadPlus(LeftCatch) and MonadPlus(LeftDistributive)?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14143/10336). After composing  the question I believe it won't be very hard to get a complete picture.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Yup - now we have a very complete picture I think. Thanks.