# Why is there not 'Alternative' instance for 'Control.Applicative.Const'

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids, alternative-functor

There is an instance `Monoid a => Monoid (Const a b)` for the [`Const`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Const) functor from `Control.Applicative`. There is also an instance `Monoid m => Applicative (Const m)`.

I would therefore expect that there is also an instance `Monoid m => Alternative (Const m)` that coincides with the one for `Monoid`. Is this just an omission that should be fixed, or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: There is *nothing* deep about `Alternative`. Like `MonadPlus`, no one can even agree what its laws are supposed to be, and its most compelling use case is a sort of *pun*. Do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there *is* a deeper reason. While it seems there is no canonical set of rules for `Alternative`, in order for `Alternative` to make sense, there definitely ought to be a relationship between `Alternative` and its `Applicative` operations (otherwise it'd be just an arbitrary monoid.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13081604/1333025) to [Confused by the meaning of the 'Alternative' type class and its relationship to other type classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080606/confused-by-the-meaning-of-the-alternative-type-class-and-its-relationship-to) states these laws

> 1. **Right distributivity (of `<*>`):**  `(f <|> g) <*> a = (f <*> a) <|> (g <*> a)`
> 2. **Right absorption (for `<*>`):**  `empty <*> a = empty`
> 3. **Left distributivity (of `fmap`):**  `f <$> (a <|> b) = (f <$> a) <|> (f <$> b)`
> 4. **Left absorption (for `fmap`):**  `f <$> empty = empty`

which make a lot of sense to me. Roughly speaking, `empty` and `<|>` are to `pure` and `<$>`/`<*>` what 0 and + are to 1 and *.

Now if we add instance `Monoid m => Alternative (Const m)` that coincides with the one for `Monoid` / `Applicative`, the Right- laws don't hold.

For example, 2. fails, because

```
empty <*> (Const x)
= Const mempty <*> Const x    -- by the suggested definition of Alternative
= Const $ mempty `mappend` x  -- by the definition of <*> for COnst
= Const x                     -- by monoid laws
```

which isn't equal to `empty = Const mempty`. Similarly, 1. fails, a simple counter-example is setting `f = Const (Sum 1); g = Const (Sum 1) ; a = Const (Sum 1)`.

See also:

- [What are the relations between Alternative, MonadPlus(LeftCatch) and MonadPlus(LeftDistributive)?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14143/10336)
- [What’s an example of a Monad which is an Alternative but not a MonadPlus?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13122489/1333025)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed, well-written answer. I agree that these laws do make sense.