# Why is there no alternative instance for Either but a semigroup that behaves similarily to alternative?

Tags: haskell, either, alternative-functor, semigroup

I am a Haskell newbie and I wonder why there is no alternative instance for `Either` but a semigroup, which behaves as I would expect it from alternative:

```
instance Semigroup (Either a b) where
Left _ <> b = b
a      <> _ = a
```

This instance discards or corrects "errors" and when both operands are tagged with `Right`, it takes the first. Isn't this exactly the "choice" that alternative offers?

I would expect the semigroup instance to look roughly like:

```
instance (Semigroup b) => Semigroup (Either a b) where
Left e  <> _       = Left e
_       <> Left e  = Left e
Right x <> Right y = Right (x <> y)
```

That means it propagates errors and appends regular results.

I guess I have either a wrong notion of `Either` or of the involved type classes.

Comment: This looks related: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9588

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What would you expect an `Alternative` instance to give you. I think a good way for you to get a feel for how `Alternative` and `Semigroup` differ is to look at another type that has instances for both: for example `Maybe String`:

```
λ > Just "a" <> Just "b"
Just "ab"
λ > Just "a" <> Nothing
Just "a"
λ > Nothing <> Just "b"
Just "b"
λ > Nothing <> Nothing
Nothing


λ > Just "a" <|> Just "b"
Just "a"
λ > Just "a" <|> Nothing
Just "a"
λ > Nothing <|> Just "b"
Just "b"
λ > Nothing <|> Nothing
Nothing
```

Alright, so the main difference seems to be for `Just "a"` and `Just "b"`. This makes sense since you are combining them in the case of the `Semigroup` rather than taking the left biased option in the case of `Alternative`.

Now why couldn't you have an `Alternative` instance for `Either`. If you look at the functions which are part of the `Alternative` type class:

```
λ > :i Alternative
class Applicative f => Alternative (f :: * -> *) where
  empty :: f a
  (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
  some :: f a -> f [a]
  many :: f a -> f [a]
  {-# MINIMAL empty, (<|>) #-}
```

It looks like it defines a notion of `empty`; this is the identity of the `(<|>)` operator. The identity in the case means that the alternative between the identity and something else is always that something else.

Now, how would you construct an identity for `Either e a`? If you look at the constraint on the `Alternative` instance, you can see that it requires `f` to have an `Applicative` instance. That's fine, `Either` has an `Applicative` instance declared for `Either e`. As you can see the `Either` is only an applicative functor on the second type variable (`a` in the case of `Either e a`). So an identity for `Either e` would need `e` to also have an identity. While it is possible to construct a type where `e` has an instance of `Alternative` you can't make an instance for `Alternative` for `Either` with that `e` because no such constraint is in the type class definition (something along the lines of: `(Alternative e, Applicative (f e)) => Alternative (f e)`).

**TL;DR**: I am sorry if I lost you with my rambling, the short of it is that `f` in the case of `Either` is of the wrong *kind*, `Alternative` requires `f :: * -> *` while `Either` is of *kind* `Either :: * -> * -> *`

So `Maybe` can have an instance of `Alternative` because it has *kind* `Maybe : * -> *` and has a notion of identity (`Nothing`) that is required by `empty`. Have a look at all the instances of [`Alternative`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative) and pay attention to the kind of each instance data type.

You can find the kind of a data type in ghci with `:k`:

```
λ > :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
λ > :k Either
Either :: * -> * -> *
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: Sorry, one issue remains: `Just "a" <> Just "b" == Just "ab"` as expected, but `Right "a" <> Right "b" == Right "a"`. Why this difference?

Comment: Right, so the instance for `Semigroup` of `Either a b` is actually not defined the way you wrote it. It is entirely independent of whether `b` has an instance of `Semigroup` or not. It basically just discards a `Left` value when it is the left term of `(<>)` and otherwise return the left term. Checkout the actual source code [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Semigroup.html#line-173) :-) I am not sure what the rationale behind this definition is but it works out pretty well for you since you seemed to want an `Alternative` instance.

Comment: @basile-henry I don't understand what's the problem with `Either` having kind `* -> * -> *`. It's not an explanation why `Either` can't be `Alternative`. For example, `Monad` also requires type to have kind `* -> *` but there's `Monad` instance for `Either` — it just implemented as `Monad (Either e)` — partially applying `Either`. For example this compiles and works as expected: https://hastebin.com/duyituzuda.hs Probably not laws are satisfied, didn't check it. But this is valid code and should be explaned, why not an option.

Comment: Well you just added a constraint that `e` needs to have an identity. It is a perfectly fine solution, and I have mentioned it (using `Alternative` instead of `Monoid` to get `empty`). I don't think you can do it without this constraint. I admit that the sentence describing this is pretty unclear and I should try to reword it better.

Answer (score 6):

Per the [ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9588) Dietrich Epp posted above, the issue with `Alternative` is `empty`. If you have:

```
instance Alternative (Either a) where ...
```

You'd need to be able to pull some value `Either a b` "out of thin air" that was your identity object. One possible instance might be:

```
instance (Monoid a)=> Alternative (Either a) where 
  empty = Left mempty
  ...
```

You also ask why the `Semigroup` instance is defined the way it is, and frankly I don't understand it either. It would seem that the instance you propose would also permit a (compatible/lawful) `Monoid` instance as well:

```
instance Monoid b=> Monoid (Either a b) where
  mempty = Right mempty
```

And this would be consistent with the `Maybe` instance (the algebraic relationship between Maybe and Either being obvious).

So the situation isn't good. Part of the issue is `Alternative` is sort of a second-class class if you will; it is a monoidal higher-kinded thingy, but its relation to `Monoid` and `Semigroup`, which obviously and explicitly (in the docs) form a hierarchy, is not defined.

I'm sure there's been a large amount of discussion on the libraries mailing list, and if there are some obvious "correct" solutions it's likely that moving to them could cause (in the worst case silent) breakage.

Comment: The alternative type class seems to frequently cause [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681260/why-is-there-not-alternative-instance-for-control-applicative-const), also because of the underlying laws. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although `Either` doesn't have an `Alternative` instance, it does have a [`Bialternative`](https://github.com/ekmett/bifunctors/issues/126) instance.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE QuantifiedConstraints #-}

class (Bifunctor p, forall a. Applicative (p a)) => Bialternative p where
  {-# MINIMAL left, ((<<|>>) | liftL2) #-}
  left :: a -> p a b

  (<<|>>) :: p (a -> b) c -> p a c -> p b c
  (<<|>>) = liftL2 id

  liftL2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> p a d -> p b d -> p c d
  liftL2 f a b = f `first` a <<|>> b

  (|>>) :: p a c -> p b c -> p b c
  a |>> b = liftL2 (const id) a b

  (<<|) :: p a c -> p b c -> p a c
  a <<| b = liftL2 const a b
```

Here's the `Bialternative` instance of `Either`. You can use `|>>` instead of `<|>`.

```hs
instance Bialternative Either where
  left :: a -> Either a b
  left = Left

  (<<|>>) :: Either (a -> b) c -> Either a c -> Either b c
  Left f <<|>> Left a = Left (f a)
  Right c <<|>> _ = Right c
  _ <<|>> Right c = Right c
```

Instances of `Bialternative` should satisfy the following laws.

***Identity***

```hs
left id <<|>> v = v
```

***Composition***

```hs
left (.) <<|>> u <<|>> v <<|>> w = u <<|>> (v <<|>> w)
```

***Homomorphism***

```hs
left f <<|>> left x = left (f x)
```

***Interchange***

```hs
u <<|>> left y = left ($ y) <<|>> u
```

***Left Catch***

```hs
pure x <<|>> v = pure x
```

***Right Catch***

```hs
left x <*> v = left x
```