# Why `guard` is not defined with a MonadPlus constraint?

Tags: haskell, monads, alternative-functor, monadplus

I am currently reading about the Alternative/MonadPlus typeclasses in [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Alternative_and_MonadPlus). It describes the difference very well. However, one puzzling part is the `guard` function, which I am assuming, is used for "short-circuiting" a computation. (Am I right?)

The function `guard` although defined in `Control.Monad` has an `Alternative` constraint, as following ([link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#guard)).

```
guard           :: (Alternative f) => Bool -> f ()
guard True      =  pure ()
guard False     =  empty
```

But the above article, mentions that only the `MonadPlus` is required to enforce the left zero and right zero laws (Hence the stronger claim).

```
mzero >>= f  =  mzero -- left zero
m >> mzero   =  mzero -- right zero
```

Given the purpose of the `guard` function, shouldn't it be defined with a `MonadPlus` constraint? Don't we need the stronger laws if `guard` is supposed to "short-circuit" the computation? I am curious about the reason behind the specific design choice.

p.s.: I don't know what is a better way to describe the "cancelling the upfront computation" behavior other than the word "short-circuiting"?

Comment: `MonadPlus` is stronger than `Alternative` and you don't need `MonadPlus` to write `guard` - the type with `Alternative` is the most general type, i.e. the inferred one. Why would one give it a stronger type? (Note the wikibooks page is outdated post-AMP, so ghc 8 and up? I don't actually remember..)

Comment: @user2407038 Don't we need the stronger laws (left zero, right zero) if guard is supposed to do "short-circuiting"?

Comment: You get 'short circuiting' in the `Applicative` context: `guard False *> x = empty` and `guard True *> x = x`; it simply also works for `Monad` in the same natural way as all things which work for `Applicative` will work for `Monad`.

Comment: @user2407038 But AFAIK `Alternative` doesn't mandate the `empty *> x == empty` law. So it might not be true for all instances. Am I right?

Comment: It's a documentation issue. `guard` was `MonadPlus m => ...`, but every `MonadPlus` is now  an `Alternative`, and by default `mzero = empty` and `mplus = (<|>)`. Therefore, if you have a type that's both a `Monad` and an `Alternative`, it should hold those laws. However, that should be stated in either the `class Alternative` or the `class Monad` documentation. That being said, the functionality of `guard` wasn't reduced. `mzero` is `empty` on all common `MonadPlus` instances.

Comment: @user2407038 That Wikibooks page was updated recently (~2 months ago) to account for the AMP. (Older versions of it didn't cover `Alternative`, only `MonadPlus`.)

Comment: Side note: I haven't seen any indication of a right zero law, and several important instances don't satisfy one.

Answer (score 0):

`guard` has an `Applicative` constraint because you don't need to perform monadic operations on it to define the function.

It's definition is (copied from the [Hackage source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.html#guard)):

```
guard           :: (Alternative f) => Bool -> f ()
guard True      =  pure ()
guard False     =  empty
```

If it had specified `MonadPlus` instead of `Alternative`, it wouldn't have gained anything.  `MonadPlus` is a subclass of `Alternative`, so all `MonadPlus` instances can use `guard`, but not all `Alternatives` could use it.

(Although there would be *very* few cases of excluded `Alternatives` -- both cases mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122489/what-s-an-example-of-a-monad-which-is-an-alternative-but-not-a-monadplus) have an instance of `MonadPlus` even though they don't satisfy the left-distributive rule.)

In general, it's better to stick to the bare minimum restrictions needed to write a function, even if the intended use is more specific.  This way, there is nothing excluded that shouldn't be, and no complaints from people whose types could work for it, but aren't monads.

Coincidentally, the [Hoogle search results](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=guard) incorrectly show a `MonadPlus` restriction instead, though if you click the link it is correct.

Comment: AFAIK the function was defined with a MonadPlus constraint and latter changed to Applicative.