# Why is Alternative concatenating lists instead of choosing the first non-empty one?

Tags: haskell, alternative-functor

From the class's name and usage in parsers and with `Maybe` I thought that it's behaviour would be to choose the first non-empty input from `a <|> b <|> c`. So I expected that for input

```
[] <|> [1] <|> [2, 3]
```

it would return the first non-empty list, i.e.:

```
[1]
```

but it actually just concats the whole thing, producing:

```
[1,2,3]
```

So I am wondering what's the reasoning behind such an implementation? Is it actually correct?

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative

P.S. Is there any standard function that does what I expected from `Alternative`?

Comment: It sounds like you want `Maybe`, not `[]`.

Comment: In addition to the good answers below, I'll give an interpretation reason. A straightforward conceptualisation of a list is a sequence of values, but you could instead interpret a list as a non-deterministic choice of values. With that interpretation, it's natural for `[] <|> [1] <|> [2,3]` to mean the same as `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When implementing an `Alternative f` (or `MonadPlus f`) instance, you have to select a monoid over `f a` and implement it using `empty` and `<|>`. For some structures, such as lists, there can be several possibilities. The most natural monoidal operation for lists is their concatenation (with `[]` being the identity element). Taking the first non-empty element, as you suggest, is also a possibility, but not as natural for lists. Your operation almost ignores the structure (the length) of lists, it only checks if a list is empty or not. And it doesn't add anything new, because this kind of monoidal operation is already available as `Maybe`'s instance of `Alternative`, which is designed to represent (non)empty values.

This is also reflected in the instance of `MonadPlus` of `[]`. As described on [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus), there are two possible sets of laws for instances of `MonadPlus`:

- Monoid + LeftZero + LeftDistribution - statisfied by `[]`
- Monoid + LeftZero + LeftCatch - statisfied by `Maybe`, `IO` and `STM`.

If we chose your implementation of `Alternative` and `MonadPlus`, then we'd have only instances satisfying `... + LeftCatch`, nothing satisfying LeftDistribution. And again, `MonadPlus` of `[]` wouldn't be very different from `MonadPlus` of `Maybe`. And we wouldn't have anything that would enable us to solve things like the [send+more=money puzzle](http://logicaltypes.blogspot.cz/2008/05/guarded-choice-with-monadplus.html). So it's much more interesting to choose the `mplus`/`<|>` of `[]` to be concatenation.

Answer (score 4):

The reason (well, *one* reason) is that it matches the `MonadPlus` instance.

As far as I can tell, it is desirable that when a type has instances for both, `MonadPlus` and `Alternative`, these instances match, since the relation of `Alternative` to `Applicative` is like the relation of `MonadPlus` to `Monad`.

For your desired behaviour, if you want to use `Alternative`, you need a `newtype` wrapper around lists, as a freestanding function, it is of course also easy to define.

```
[] <++ xs = xs
xs <++ _  = xs
```

Comment: Thanks! An implementation like `a <||> b = if a == empty then b else a` would make the function general for all `Alternative`s though

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Well, all `Alternative`s that are also `Eq`s. Some lists aren't.

Answer (score 4):

This is the intended behaviour. The `Alternative` class defines a monoid for applicative functors (hence the `(Applicative f) =>` class constraint in the definition).

`Alternative` has the same relation to `Applicative` as `MonadPlus` has to `Monad`. It makes sense that the `Alternative` instance for lists gives the same behaviour as the `MonadPlus` instance for lists (and also the same behaviour as the `Monoid` instance for lists).

This isn't the only valid definition for a list monoid though. Your definition:

```
instance Monoid [a] where
  mempty = []
  [] `mappend` xs = xs
  xs `mappend` _  = xs
```

also satisfied the monoid laws (exercise: check this!) so you could either define a newtype

```
newtype Lst a = Lst { getLst :: [a] }
```

and make that into a `Monoid`/`Alternative`/etc instance, or just define your own function to do what you want, as in Daniel Fischer's answer.

Comment: You could also look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10168111/546084) by Edward Kmett.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative is just a monoid defined for applicative functors. So an instance of Alternative for an applicative functor is correct if it satisfies the monoid laws.

I don't know if there is a standard function to do that, but you can ofcourse implement your own function or define your own instance of alternative.

You can read more about them in [typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia). Which explains all these typeclasses in detail along with their laws which are to be followed.