# Must mplus always be associative? Haskell wiki vs. Oleg Kiselyov

Tags: haskell, monads, monadplus

The [Haskell wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/MonadPlus#The_MonadPlus_laws) asserts that

> Instances of MonadPlus are required to fulfill several rules, just as instances of Monad are required to fulfill the three monad laws. ... The most essential are that mzero and mplus form a monoid.

A consequence of which is that `mplus` must be associative. The [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/MonadPlus) agrees.

However, Oleg, in [one of his many backtracking search implementations](http://okmij.org/ftp/continuations/Searches.hs), writes that

```
-- Generally speaking, mplus is not associative. It better not be,
-- since associative and non-commutative mplus makes the search
-- strategy incomplete.
```

Is it kosher to define a non-associative `mplus`? The first two links pretty clearly suggest you don't have a real `MonadPlus` instance if `mplus` isn't associative. But if *Oleg* does it ... (On the other hand, in that file he's just defining a function called `mplus`, and doesn't claim that *that* `mplus` is the `mplus` of `MonadPlus`. He chose a pretty confusing name, if that's the right interpretation.)

Comment: And you get an answer, and then the question becomes, should you trust Stack Overflow or Haskell wiki or Oleg Kiselyov.

Comment: A lot of the time, these rules are obeyed only according to certain observable properties. Iirc, the fast version of FreeT only obeys one of the MonadTrans laws (`lift . return == return` I think) if you cannot look at the structure directly, but as the constructors are hidden it's ok.

So, in this case, we could easily say that the law is kindof satisfied - as long as we only ever use a complete search strategy, we would get the same results, and can just hide what the depth of things in the search tree is. Whether it is acceptable to violate the laws a bit for convenience, who knows.

Comment: @RomanCheplyaka The monoid laws are the minimum requirement because without them the other laws are meaningless.  For example, when you say `mzero >>= f = mzero`, you first need some sensible definition of `mzero` is, but without the identity laws you don't have that.  The monoid laws are what keep the other proposed laws "honest".  If you don't have the monoid laws then you have no sensible laws and what's the point of a theoretical type class that has no laws?

Comment: A non-associative binary operation with left and right units? So you end up with a tree-like free structure instead of a list-like one. To my knowledge, the report doesn't actually specify laws. It would be semantically dangerous to introduce a rewrite rule that re-associates  `mplus`es

Comment: This might also be helpful: http://winterkoninkje.dreamwidth.org/90905.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The two laws that everybody agrees that `MonadPlus` should obey are the identity and associativity laws (a.k.a. the monoid laws):

```
mplus mempty a = a

mplus a mempty = a

mplus (mplus a b) c = mplus a (mplus b c)
```

I always assume they hold in all `MonadPlus` instances that I use and consider instances that violate those laws to be "broken", whether or not they were written by Oleg.

Oleg is right that associativity does not play nicely with breadth-first search, but that just means that `MonadPlus` is not the abstraction he is looking for.

To answer the point you made in a comment, I would always consider that rewrite rule of yours sound.

Answer (score 32):

Below is the opinion of Oleg Himself, with my comment and his clarification.

**O.K.** First I would like to register my disagreement with Gabriel
Gonzalez. Not everyone agrees that `MonadPlus` should be monoid with
respect to `mplus` and `mzero`. The Report says nothing about it. There
are many compelling cases when this is not so (see below). Generally,
the algebraic structure should fit the task. That's why we have
groups, and also weaker semi-groups or groupoids (magmas). It seems
`MonadPlus` is often regarded as a search/non-determinism monad. If so,
then the properties of `MonadPlus` should be those that facilitate
search and reasoning about search — rather than some ideal ad hoc
properties someone likes for whatever reason. Let me give an example:
it is tempting to posit the law

```
m >> mzero === mzero
```

However, monads that support search and can do other effects (think of
`NonDeT m`) cannot satisfy that law. For example,

```
print "OK" >> mzero  =/==  mzero
```

because the left-hand side prints something but the right-hand
doesn't. By the same token, `mplus` cannot be symmetric: `mplus m1 m2`
generally differs from `mplus m2 m1`, in the same model.

Let us come to `mplus`. There are two main reason NOT to require `mplus`
be associative. First is the completeness of the search. Consider

```
ones = return 1 `mplus` ones

foo = ones `mplus` return 2
  === {- inlining ones -}
  (return 1 `mplus` ones) `mplus` return 2
  === {- associativity -}
  return 1 `mplus` (ones `mplus` return 2)
  ===
  return 1 `mplus` foo
```

It would seem therefore, coinductively ones and foo are the same. That
means, we will never get the answer 2 from foo.

That results holds for ANY search that can be represented by `MonadPlus`, so
long as `mplus` is associative and non-commutative. Therefore, if `MonadPlus` is a
monad for search, then associativity of `mplus` is an unreasonable requirement.

Here is the second reason: sometimes we wish for a probabilistic
search — or, in general, weighted search, when some alternatives are
weighted. It is obvious that the probabilistic choice operator is not
associative. For that reason, our JFP paper specifically avoids
imposing monoid (`mplus`, `mzero`) structure on `MonadPlus`.

http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/monads.html#lazy-sharing-nondet
(see the discussion around Figure 1 of the paper).

**R.C.**
I think Gabriel and you agree on the fact that search monads do not
exhibit the monoid structure. The argument boils down to whether
`MonadPlus` should be used for search monads or should there be another
class, let's call it `MonadPlus'`, which is just like `MonadPlus` but with
more lax laws. As you say, the report doesn't say anything on this
topic, and there's no authority to decide.

For the purpose of reasoning, I don't see any problem with that — one
just has to state clearly her assumptions about the `MonadPlus` instances.

As for the rewrite rule that re-associates `mplus`'es, the mere existence
and widespread use of `MonadPlus` instances that are not associative,
regardless of whether they are "broken", means that one should probably
abstain from defining it.

**O.K.**
I guess I disagree with Gabriel's statement

> The monoid laws are the minimum requirement because
>   without them the other laws are meaningless. For example, when you say
>   `mzero >>= f = mzero`, you first need some sensible definition of
>   `mzero` is, but without the identity laws you don't have that. The
>   monoid laws are what keep the other proposed laws "honest". If you don't
>   have the monoid laws then you have no sensible laws and what's the point
>   of a theoretical type class that has no laws?

For example, LogicT paper and especially the JFP paper has lots of
examples of equational reasoning about non-determinism, without
associativity of `mplus`. The JFP paper omits all monoid laws for `mplus`
and `mzero` (but uses `mzero >>= f === mzero`). It seems one can have
"honest" and "sensible laws" for non-determinism and search without
the monoid laws for `mplus` and `mzero`.

I'm also not sure I agree with the claim

> The two laws that everybody agrees that `MonadPlus` should obey are
>   the identity and associativity laws (a.k.a. the monoid laws):

I'm not sure a poll has been taken on this. The Report states no laws
for `mplus` (perhaps the authors were still debating them). So, I
would say the issue is open — and this is the main message to get
across.

Comment: In the absence of enforceable contracts we must agree as a community (i.e. take a poll) on what the laws should be and I don't believe sacrificing the monoid laws is worth it just to satisfy the very specialized needs of Oleg's library.  He is perfectly welcome to define his own type class with his own set of laws if he disagrees with the community.

Comment: What makes you think that his needs are specialized? I don't remember using `MonadPlus` for anything except parsing and search (perhaps also for `Maybe` a couple of times). Do you have many useful examples of monoidal `MonadPlus` instances?

Comment: Web frameworks use `MonadPlus` for routing, there's parsing like you mentioned, also my own `ListT`'s from `pipes` use `MonadPlus`, `MaybeT`/`EitherT e` (if `e` is a `Monoid`), and also Edward's "free `MonadPlus`" in the `free` package.

Comment: I thought `0 + m === m`, not `0 + m === 0`.

Comment: @Heimdell The thing is `(>>)` is not part of the `MonadPlus` class, but `mplus` is. So `mplus mzero m === m` indeed (this is the “identity” law) that is discussed here. As well as `return >=> m === m` for `Monad`. The `mzero >> m === mzero` law means that `MonadPlus` gives a multiplicative structure on top of `Monad` and, well, yes, this “Plus” part in its name may be misleading.

Answer (score 4):

It's rare that `MonadPlus` instances violate associativity, but clearly not impossible. Typeclasses can only be counted to satisfy the "obvious" laws up to a certain amount. For instance, four further sets of possible laws for `MonadPlus` [are discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167879/distinction-between-typeclasses-monadplus-alternative-and-monoid) without any conclusion and with libraries following various conventions without specifying which.

Clearly, Oleg has a reason to dismiss associativity. Is it "truly a `MonadPlus` instance"? Who knows, it's not well enough defined to say.

Comment: It's clearly *possible* to write `MonadPlus` instances that aren't associative, just as it's possible to write `Monoid` instances that aren't associative or `Monad` instances that violate a monad law. What I want to know is whether it's ok to *act as if* all `MonadPlus` instances are associative, and say, if undesired behavior crops up in a non-associative instance, "you brought that on yourself".

Comment: (The context here is that I'm working on a monad lib for clojure and I want to know whether it would be licit to rewrite `(mplus (mplus a b) c)` into `(mplus a (mplus b c))`. That rewriting makes it easier for me to avoid a stack overflow, but obviously I don't want to do it it's *legal* to have those computations result in different answers.)

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back--essentially, if there were any known rewrite rules which assume things about the monad typeclasses. The response seemed to be negative.

Comment: So, I'd say it's up to you. If you describe `MonadPlus` as the set of monoids in the category of a Monads then you can assume association. There's clearly no guarantee that all the Haskell `MonadPlus`es will still function properly, though.