# Why is there no type class for monoids on functors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, monoids, alternative-functor

I admit that this question is a bit unspecific, but I was wondering why I never stumbled upon a type class for monoids on functors in Haskell. Did I just miss it, is there good reason for this absence or is it entirely due to historic causes? IMHO, the following inheritance chart looks a bit odd without a top right corner:

```
  Functor
     |
     V
Applicative ––> Alternative
     |               |
     V               V
   Monad    ––>  MonadPlus
```

Comment: you can always add it (and there is probably some CT lib around that does if it can be reasonable defined) - my best guess: there where just no/not-enough use-cases

Comment: I would disagree that you can always add it as you cannot make it a superclass of Alternative. I also think that (almost) every use-case for Alternative/MonadPlus is actually a use-case for this missing class. But perhaps I'm a bit too idealistic here.

Comment: Doesn't the `Monoid` class already cover this? Could you elaborate on what methods you think that class should have beyond those already offered by `Monoid`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One key factor to think about here is, "What does the arrow from `Functor` really mean?" If there are no *axioms* that unify `Functor` with `FunctorPlus` then you might as well just define `instance Monoid (F t) where ...` and be done with it. So what axioms are you looking for -- just `fmap f fempty = fempty` or also `fmap f x <|> fmap f y == fmap f (x <|> y)`...?

Another key factor will be the dearth of interesting structures which are functors but not applicatives. There's probably an argument having to do with generic-programming (metaprogramming the `deriving` keyword) where everything is a sum of products and therefore we can derive `Applicative` for anything of kind `* -> *`, but I don't know the details. The only value `FunctorPlus` could possibly have is "doing the same thing that Alternative does for Functors which are not Applicative," and so if that set is really small then there's obviously not much value added.

Comment: I disagree with your premise that non-applicative functors aren't relevant. Even if an applicative instance is _possible_, it's often neither obvious nor really useful. Whereas a `Functor` instance is always canonical – if it's possible at all, then there can be no ambiguity how it behaves, and the instance can automatically be added by means of the `-XDeriveFunctor` instance.

Comment: @leftroundabout I agree with your disagreement. This is an answer in the sense of "here are some reasons why it maybe hasn't been done yet," not, "here is why it can't / shouldn't be done," so I am only saying "you could usually use a monoid and usually the functor is applicative."

Comment: I'm tempted to say I'd like to choose the axioms such that `FunctorPlus` adds as much to `Functor` as `Alternative` adds to `Applicative`. Whatever thats means precisely. But I've just noticed that `Alternative` adds nothing more than being a `Monoid`. So, perhaps I should have asked for the actual use of `Alternative` over `Applicative` + `Monoid`. Anyways, thinking about my intended use-case once more made me realize that `FunctorPlus` wouldn't be of any help for it.

Comment: @MartinHuschenbett see also [this answer by Master Kmett](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167879/distinction-between-typeclasses-monadplus-alternative-and-monoid) which insists that there is an implicit axiom to the effect of `empty <*> x = empty` (and probably also `f <*> empty = empty`?) that Alternatives should satisfy.