# Why does the Alternative typeclass need to be a sub-class of Control.Applicative

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids, alternative-functor

Haskell provides a standard typeclass 'Alternative' that effectively provides the `<|>` operator for any type that is also an Applicative.

As I understand it Alternative is considered a Monoid on Applicative's, however the `<|>` operator seems to make complete sense in a lot of types that aren't Applicative Functors as well, and there doesn't need to be any specific dependency on the Applicative typeclass for it to work properly.

Is there a reason why Alternative needs to be a subclass of Applicative, and if so is there a standard typeclass to define similar functionality on non-applicative types?

Comment: `Monoid` would be the class for non-applicative types.

Comment: @Lee, that doesn't quite kind-check, as `Monoid` is a class of types and `Alternative` is a class of type constructors. I wish we could have locally quantified constraints on type constructors, such as `(forall a. Monoid f a)` but that's not allowed.

Comment: Technically Alternative is just "Monoid for Applicatives", so "Monoid" would seem to be the more common case, as I understand it the expected use of the `<|>` operator is "Pick or ore another", which is somewhat different to `mconcat`?

Comment: It seems to me that all the category-theory typeclasses are a bit tangled together, mostly due to historical considerations (i.e., backwards compatibility). I think this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167879/distinction-between-typeclasses-monadplus-alternative-and-monoid"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `Alt` from the `semigroupoids` package comes closest to being a 'standard' typeclass. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.0.0.1/docs/Data-Functor-Alt.html#t:Alt

Comment: It'd be nicer if `Alt` was a superclass of `Alternative`, and `Apply` a superclass of `Applicative`, wouldn't it?

Comment: And I seem to miss a an instance to work with this `Alt` as a Semigroup. (Analoguously to [the `Alt` newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#g:5) which makes it possible to use an `Alternative` as a Monoid.)

Comment: Regrettably, being a semigroup, it doesn't have `altEmpty :: f a`.