# Cleaning up noise in MaybeT

Tags: haskell

I am sure many of you have seen code like this:

```
someFunc :: MaybeT IO ()
someFunc = do
    foo1 <- MaybeT $ ...
    foo2 <- MaybeT . return $ ...
    foo3 <- lift $ ...
    foo4 <- liftIO $ ...
    ...
```

I am talking about those `MaybeT`, `MaybeT . return`, `lift`, `liftIO`, etc.

This type of noise clutters up my `MaybeT` code.

I have the feeling there is a better way. Is there?

Comment: Could you add a complete example? This is hard to answer without seeing the right hand sides.

Comment: This sort of problem is generally solved by using `mtl`. In your case, because you are using `MaybeT`, it is not as obvious how to do this. Slightly confusingly, the `MonadMaybe` constraint one might want is just `MonadPlus` (see [this pull request](https://github.com/ekmett/mtl/issues/6)). This would be easier to answer if your example was more complete (ie compileable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
someFunc :: MaybeT IO ()
```

To be consistent with the advice below, rewrite `someFunc :: (Alternative m, MonadIO m) => m ()`. This is not needed for implementing `someFunc`, but is needed for using `someFunc` in other operations without explicit lifting when the other operations are not specifically in the `MaybeT IO` monad.

```
someFunc = do
    foo1 <- MaybeT $ ...
```

Rewrite `...` to use `return` and `empty` instead of `return . Just` and `return Nothing`.

```
    foo2 <- MaybeT . return $ ...
```

Rewrite `...` to use `return` and `empty` instead of `Just` and `Nothing`.

```
    foo3 <- lift $ ...
```

For `MaybeT IO`, the `lift` and `liftIO` operations are identical, so see the next suggestion. In the general case (rather than specific to `MaybeT IO`), rewrite `...` to be typeclass polymorphic for a class that your concrete monad inhabits.

```
    foo4 <- liftIO $ ...
```

Can't do much about this. Sometimes it is possible to give `...` a `MonadIO` constraint rather than an `IO` type. Usually that just shifts the location of the `liftIO`, though; it has to appear somewhere.

Comment: Clearly `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` are identical here. Are there conventions on when to use which as constraints? (I've read [this excellent answer by Edward Kmett](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167879/distinction-between-typeclasses-monadplus-alternative-and-monoid)).

Comment: @Alec If you can give your operation an `Alternative`-polymorphic type, you probably should: as noted there, `MonadPlus` is a stronger claim, hence has fewer instances, is "less polymorphic" in a sense, and can not be used at as many different types by the caller. On the other hand, sometimes something you write assumes one of the `MonadPlus` laws, in which case you have no choice but to upgrade from `Alternative` to `MonadPlus`.