# Keeping IO lazy under append

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, monoids, semigroup

I may have been under the false impression that Haskell is lazier than it is, but I wonder if there's a way to get the best of both worlds...

`Data.Monoid` and `Data.Semigroup` define two variations of `First`. The monoidal version models the leftmost, non-empty value, whereas the semigroup version simply models the leftmost value.

This works fine for pure value values, but consider impure values:

```
x = putStrLn "x" >> return 42
y = putStrLn "y" >> return 1337
```

Both of these values have the type `Num a => IO a`. `IO a` is a `Semigroup` instance when `a` is:

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (IO a)
  -- Defined in `Data.Orphans'
```

This means that it's possible to combine two `IO (First a)` values:

```
Prelude Data.Semigroup Data.Orphans> fmap First x <> fmap First y
x
y
First {getFirst = 42}
```

As we can see, though, both `x` and `y` produce their respective side-effects, even though `y` is never required.

The same applies for `Data.Monoid`:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> fmap (First . Just) x <> fmap (First . Just) y
x
y
First {getFirst = Just 42}
```

I think I understand why this happens, given that both the `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances use `liftA2`, which seems to ultimately be based on `IO` *bind*, which is strict, as far as I understand it.

If I dispense with the `First` abstraction(s), however, I can get lazier evaluation:

```
first x _ = x

mfirst x y = do
  x' <- x
  case x' of
    (Just _) -> return x'
    Nothing -> y
```

Using both of those ignores `y`:

```
Prelude> first x y
x
42
Prelude> mfirst (fmap Just x) (fmap Just y)
x
Just 42
```

In both of these cases, `y` isn't printed.

My question is, then:

*Can I get the best of both worlds? Is there a way that I can retain the Semigroup or Monoid abstraction, while still get lazy IO?*

Is there, for example, some sort of `LazyIO` container that I can wrap `First` values in, so that I get the lazy IO I'd like to have?

The actual scenario I'm after is that I'd like to query a prioritised list of IO resources for data, and use the first one that gives me a useful response. I don't, however, want to perform redundant queries (for performance reasons).

Comment: Do you need the semigroup/monoid abstraction, or the `First` abstraction (aka early exit from `IO` functions)?

Comment: @Zeta Ideally, I'd prefer to keep the semigroup/monoid abstraction, but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: You could try to write your own instance for `Semigroup a => Semigroup (IO a)` that satisfies the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin Would `FirstIO (launchMissiles *> return Nothing) <> FirstIO (return (Just 'x'))` be equal to `FirstIO (return Nothing) <> FirstIO (return (Just 'x'))`?

Comment: @danidiaz Since the `IO` packed inside `FirstIO (launchMissiles *> return Nothing)` is not the same as the `IO` packed inside `FirstIO (return Nothing)`, I would say no, they are not equal. The bit after the `<>` never factors into the evaluation.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I think you are right, and it would be a valid `Monoid`. In fact, the `Alternative` instance for `MaybeT` in transformers is already very similar: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thinking about this a bit more, what exactly is enforcing laziness in this monoid abstraction pushed through `IO` buying you? In other words, what use-cases would not be covered by the trivial `instance Semigroup (IO (First a)) where (<>) ia ib = ia` (with `FlexibleInstances` enabled)? See [demo](https://ideone.com/v9RRv0).

Comment: Relevant: http://www.parsonsmatt.org/2016/11/18/clean_alternatives_with_maybet.html and also http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin A couple of quick tests with your suggestion seems to indicate that this actually solves my problem. If it's really that simple, I'd be happy. You're welcome to add that as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I'm not sure I follow... With the `Semigroup` instance for `IO` in `Data.Orphans`, `getFirst <$> (First <$> x) <> (First <$> y)` executes both `x` and `y`...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Sorry, made a mistake there. I meant to write `getFirst $ (First x) <> (First y)`. This is basically the same thing as what that instance from the earlier comment is doing: just picking the first `IO`. [Here's](https://www.ideone.com/PVe1uC) a demo.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin I see... In reality, my question is an attempt at simplifying my actual situation. What I really have is a series of functions that return `IO (Maybe MyData)`, and I map those to `IO (Option (First MyData))` in order to choose the leftmost, non-empty value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Alternative` instance for the [`MaybeT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html) monad transformer returns the first successful result, and does not execute the rest of the operations. In combination with the [`asum`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum) function, we can write something like:

```
import Data.Foldable (asum)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

action :: Char -> IO Char
action c = putChar c *> return c

main :: IO ()
main = do
    result <- runMaybeT $ asum $ [ empty
                                 , MaybeT $ action 'x' *> return Nothing
                                 , liftIO $ action 'v'
                                 , liftIO $ action 'z'
                                 ]
    print result
```

where the final `action 'z'` won't be executed.

We can also write a newtype wrapper with a `Monoid` instance which mimics the `Alternative`:

```
newtype FirstIO a = FirstIO (MaybeT IO a)

firstIO :: IO (Maybe a) -> FirstIO a
firstIO ioma = FirstIO (MaybeT ioma)

getFirstIO :: FirstIO a -> IO (Maybe a)
getFirstIO (FirstIO (MaybeT ioma)) = ioma

instance Monoid (FirstIO a) where
    mempty = FirstIO empty
    FirstIO m1 `mappend` FirstIO m2 = FirstIO $ m1 <|> m2
```

The relationship between `Alternative` and `Monoid` is explained in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167879/distinction-between-typeclasses-monadplus-alternative-and-monoid/10168111#10168111).

Comment: Perfect, the `newtype`-based instance of `Monoid` (and `Semigroup`) was just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I can retain the Semigroup or Monoid abstraction, while still get lazy IO?

Somewhat, but there are drawbacks. The udnerlying problem for our instances is that a generic instance for an `Applicative` will look like

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (SomeApplicative a) where
    x <> y = (<>) <$> x <*> y
```

We're here at the mercy of `(<*>)`, and usually the second argument `y` will be at least in WHNF. For example in `Maybe`'s implementation the first line will work fine and the second line will `error`:

```
liftA2 (<>) Just (First 10) <> Just (error "never shown")
liftA2 (<>) Just (First 10) <> error "fire!"
```

`IO`'s `(<*>)` is implemented in terms of `ap`, so the second action will *always* be executed before `<>` is applied.

A `First`-like variant is possible with [`ExceptT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#g:2) or similar, essentially any data type that has a `Left k >>= _ = Left k` like case so that we can stop the computation at that point. Although `ExceptT` is meant for exceptions, it may work well for your use-case. Alternatively, one of the `Alternative` transformers (`MaybeT`, `ExceptT`) together with `<|>` instead of `<>` might suffice.

---

A almost completely lazy IO type is also possible, but must be handled with care:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafeInterleaveIO)  

newtype LazyIO a = LazyIO { runLazyIO :: IO a }

instance Functor LazyIO where
  fmap f = LazyIO . fmap f . runLazyIO

instance Applicative LazyIO where
  pure    = LazyIO . pure
  f <*> x = LazyIO $ do
              f' <- unsafeInterleaveIO (runLazyIO f)
              x' <- unsafeInterleaveIO (runLazyIO x)
              return $ f' x'

instance Monad LazyIO where
  return  = pure
  f >>= k = LazyIO $ runLazyIO f >>= runLazyIO . k

instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (LazyIO a) where
  (<>) = liftA2 (<>)

instance Monoid a => Monoid (LazyIO a) where
  mempty  = pure mempty
  mappend = liftA2 mappend
```

[`unsafeInterleaveIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafeInterleaveIO) will enable the behaviour you want (and is used in `getContents` and other lazy IO `Prelude` functions), but it must be used with care. The order of `IO` operations is completely off at that point. Only when we inspect the values we will trigger the original `IO`:

```
ghci> :module +Data.Monoid Control.Monad
ghci> let example = fmap (First . Just) . LazyIO . putStrLn $ "example"
ghci> runLazyIO $ fmap mconcat $ replicateM 100 example
First {getFirst = example
Just ()}
```

Note that we only got our `example` once in the output, but at a completely random place, since the `putStrLn "example"` and `print result` got *interleaved*, since

```
print (First x) = putStrLn (show (First x))
                = putStrLn ("First {getFirst = " ++ show x ++ "}")
```

and `show x` will finally put the `IO` necessary to get `x` in action. The action will get called only once if we use the result multiple times:

```
ghci> :module +Data.Monoid Control.Monad
ghci> let example = fmap (First . Just) . LazyIO . putStrLn $ "example"
ghci> result <- runLazyIO $ fmap mconcat $ replicateM 100 example
ghci> result
First {getFirst = example
Just ()}
ghci> result
First {getFirst = Just ()}
```

You could write a `finalizeLazyIO` function that either `evaluate`s or `seq`'s `x` though:

```
finalizeLazyIO :: LazyIO a -> IO a
finalizeLazyIO k = do
  x <- runLazyIO k
  x `seq` return x
```

If you were to publish a module with this functions, I'd recommend to only export the type constructor `LazyIO`, `liftIO :: IO a -> LazyIO a` and `finalizeLazyIO`.