# How to use filterM with an infinite list

Tags: haskell, monads

I was trying to find a directory name by appending a number until I found a name that doesn't yet exist:

```
head <$> filterM (fmap not . fexists_) [ getDatedDir t d n | n <- [0..] ]
```

The problem with this is that it never returns.  I think the problem is that although IO is a Functor, filterM has to do all the IO before the head effects; that is, it has to evaluate fexists for every n - and that's of course infinite.

Now, I can solve this:

```
go t d 0
where go t d n = do
    let dir = getDatedDir t d n
    fexists_ dir >>= \case
        False -> return dir
        True  -> go t d (n+1)
```

But I feel that there ought to be a more elegant approach, using filterM or something similar.

This feels like a common enough pattern that there is probably an extisting function in Control.Monad, I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: You could use `asum` to collapse an infinite list of `MaybeT IO` actions and get the first that succeeds, a bit like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120384/keeping-io-lazy-under-append/47126169#47126169

Comment: Laziness and IO sometimes don't mix well. You may check [System.IO.Lazy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lazyio-0.1.0.4/docs/System-IO-Lazy.html) to turn your IO operations into lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's `firstM` from `Control.Monad.Loops`:

```
firstM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
```

> return the first value from a list, if any, satisfying the given
>   predicate.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm after.  Thanks!  Glad to see that I wasn't missing something in Control.Monad .

Answer (score 2):

An equivalent without monads, would be `find :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Maybe a`. But I can not find a version to let it work with monads.

An idea might be to implement `findM` ourselves:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)

findM :: Monad m => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m (Maybe a)
findM f [] = return Nothing
findM f (x:xs) = f x >>= bool (findM f xs) (return (Just x))
```

You can then use it like:

```
import System.Directory(doesFileExist)

main = do
    Just fln <- findM (not . doesDirectoryExist) (map (getDatedDir t d) [0..])
    putStrLn fln
```

to print the first filename such that the file does not exists. Of course you can also process `fln` in a different way.

Comment: There's some [similarly-typed existing code](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/llvm-hs-pure-5.1.0/docs/src/LLVM.Prelude.html#findM) but nothing standard, it looks like...

Comment: @ephemient: indeed. `find` was the closest non-monad version of this problem. But `findM` does not seem to exist in a standard package, nor did a Hoogle search yield any result.