# Standard combinator to get first "non-empty" value from a set of monadic actions

Tags: haskell, monads, alternative-functor

I'm sure I am missing something very obvious here. Here's what I'm trying to achieve at a conceptual level:

```
action1 :: (MonadIO m) => m [a]
action1 = pure []

action2 :: (MonadIO m) => m [a]
action2 = pure [1, 2, 3]

action3 :: (MonadIO m) => m [a]
action3 = error "should not get evaluated"

someCombinator [action1, action2, action3] == m [1, 2, 3]
```

Does this hypothetical `someCombinator` exist? I have tried playing round with `<|>` and `msum` but couldn't get what I want.

I guess, this could be generalised in two ways:

```
-- Will return the first monadic value that is NOT an mempty 
-- (should NOT blindly execute all monadic actions)
-- This is something like the msum function

someCombinator :: (Monoid a, Monad m, Traversable t, Eq a) => t m a -> m a

-- OR

-- this is something like the <|> operator

someCombinator :: (Monad m, Alternative f) => m f a -> m f a -> m f a
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `Monoid a` is not enough to test whether a given value is "empty" or not. You'd also need `Eq a` so you can compare with `mempty`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin thanks for the tip. Updated the code snippet in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a library that provides this, but it's not hard to implement:

```
someCombinator :: (Monoid a, Monad m, Foldable t, Eq a) => t (m a) -> m a 
someCombinator = foldr f (pure mempty)
    where
        f item next = do
            a <- item
            if a == mempty then next else pure a
```

Note that you don't even need `Traversable`: `Foldable` is enough.

Comment: Just ended up writing something similar at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59798509/filter-for-first-matching-monadic-action-without-evaluating-all-actions -- I'm surprised something like `filterFirstM` doesn't already exist in the standard library.

Comment: Actually, I'm unable to wrap my head around your `foldlr`-based implementation. Is this going to give me the first "non-empty" value from L-to-R or R-to-L?

Comment: Left to right. Keep in mind that `foldr f z [x1, x2, x3] == f x1 (f x2 (f x3 z))`

Comment: The foldr based implementation is better than my foldl based implementation. I'll keep this question open for a few days, to see if someone comes up with an in-build/standard combinator.

Comment: btw, doesn't this need to be be `foldrM` instead of simply `foldr`?

Comment: I'm still stuck with `foldl` vs `foldr`. In `foldl` the initial value is the very first value of the accumulator/memo. In `foldr` is the initial value actually the LAST value (or terminal) value of the accumulator? It has to be, otherwise this is going to evaluate every single action, right?

Comment: @SaurabhNanda Keep in mind that `foldr f z [x1, x2, x3 ...] == f x1 (foldr f z [x2, x3 ...])`. so the rest of list `[x2, x3 ...]` is still unexplored when `f` is called with its two arguments -- `x1` and `(foldr f z [x2, x3 ...])`. and *if* `f` is lazy enough and won't demand the value of its second argument before returning a result, then, the rest of list `[x2, x3 ...]` will remain unexplored when the result is returned. this means the input list is explored left-to-right when `f` is non-strict in its second argument.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda see if the equivalent rewrite `f item next = do {
                a <- item ;
                if a == mempty 
                  then 
                       do { r <- next 
                          ; return r }
                  else 
                       return a }` is clearer for you. --- and no, `foldrM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> b -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b` so it uses the `a -> b -> m b` combining function to turn `t a` into `m b`, but `f :: m a -> m a -> m a` and `foldr f (pure mempty)` turns `t (m a)` into  `m a`.

Comment: and if it were `a ~ m b`, we'd have `foldrM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (m b -> b -> m b) -> b -> t (m b) -> m b` which is still not the same.

Answer (score 2):

On an abstract level, *the first non-empty value* is a `Monoid` called `First`. It turns out, however, that if you just naively lift your `IO` values into `First`, you'll have a problem with `action3`, [since the default monoidal append operation is strict under `IO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47120384/126014).

You can get lazy monoidal computation using the `FirstIO` type from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47126169/126014). It's not going to be better than Fyodor Soikin's answer, but it highlights (I hope) how you can compose behaviour from universal abstractions.

Apart from the above-mentioned `FirstIO` wrapper, you may find this function useful:

```
guarded :: Alternative f => (a -> Bool) -> a -> f a
guarded p x = if p x then pure x else empty
```

I basically just copied it from [Protolude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/protolude) since I couldn't find one in *base* that has the desired functionality. You can use it to wrap your lists in `Maybe` so that they'll fit with `FirstIO`:

```
> guarded (not . null) [] :: Maybe [Int]
Nothing
> guarded (not . null) [1, 2, 3] :: Maybe [Int]
Just [1,2,3]
```

Do this for each action in your list of actions and wrap them in `FirstIO`.

```
> :t (firstIO . fmap (guarded (not . null))) <$> [action1, action2, action3]
(firstIO . fmap (guarded (not . null))) <$> [action1, action2, action3]
  :: Num a => [FirstIO [a]]
```

In the above GHCi snippet, I'm only showing the type with `:t`. I can't show the value, since `FirstIO` has no `Show` instance. The point, however, is that you now have a list of `FirstIO` values from which `mconcat` will pick the first non-empty value:

```
> getFirstIO $ mconcat $ (firstIO . fmap (guarded (not . null))) <$> [action1, action2, action3]
Just [1,2,3]
```

If you want to unpack the `Maybe`, you can use `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`:

```
answer :: IO [Integer]
answer =
  fromMaybe [] <$>
  (getFirstIO $ mconcat $ (firstIO . fmap (guarded (not . null))) <$> [action1, action2, action3])
```

This is clearly more complex than Fyodor Soikin's answer, but I'm fascinated by how Haskell enables you to assembling desired functionality by sort of 'clicking together' existing things, almost like Lego bricks.

So, to the question of *does this combinator already exist?* the answer is that it sort of does, but some assembly is required.

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed answer, Mark. I learnt about `First` and `FirstIO` from your answer. However, as you have noted, Fyodor's answer has lesser moving parts and is simpler to implement/understand.