# How to skip unnecessary IOs in pure functions?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, applicative, pure-function

### Update

There is an extra limit of this question,
which is to avoid `IO` as much as possible.

This limit was originally placed at the end of my question,
which seems to be hard to be noticed.

I actually know how to achieve my goal in Haskell,
just as I know how to do it in other imperative programming languages - the imperative way.

But I am not using any other imperative programming, right?
I am using Haskell.
I'd like a Haskell way, a pure way.

I have reorganized my question by relocating the extra limit at a relatively conspicuous place.
That was my bad.
Lots of thanks to those quick responses.

### Original Question

```hs
main :: IO ()
main =
    putStrLn =<< cachedOrFetched
        <$> getLine
        <*> getLine

cachedOrFetched :: String -> String -> String
cachedOrFetched cached fetched =
    if not $ null cached
    then cached
    else fetched
```

The above code performs IO for twice.
But the desired behavior is to skip the second IO
when the result of the first IO is not null.

I know I can achieve this by using `do` or `when`.
Given using too many `do`s violates my original intention using Haskell,
I probably gonna live with `when`.

Or is there a better way? A purer way?

### Here is the entire thing

I started learning Haskell about two weeks ago.
I am not expecting a job from it,
but simply attracted by programming language itself.
Because it's the "purest" as far as I know.

At first, everything seemed as good as I expected.
But then I found I have to write `IO`s among my pure code.
I spent quite a long time to find a way to do impure-taint-control.
Applicative Functor seemed to be the rescue.

With it, I can "curry" the impure IOs into my pure functions,
which saves a lot of `do`, `<-` and explicit `IO` notations.
However, I got stuck with this very problem -
I am not able to skip unnecessary IOs in pure functions.

Again, a lot of searches and read.
Unfortunately, no satisfying answer till now.

### References

- [Avoiding IO](https://wiki.haskell.org/Avoiding_IO)
- [How to get rid of IO](https://wiki.haskell.org/How_to_get_rid_of_IO)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47120384/126014

Comment: @MarkSeemann Technically, it does. One thing about Applicative Functor that I appreciate most is the elegance it provides. I need to check if I can still keep the elegance with the techniques mentioned in the post. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To skip IO, you must tell the `cachedOrFetched` that you're doing IO, instead of passing two strings to it *after* reading both lines. Only then, it can conditionally run the second `getLine` IO action. Of course, `cachedOrFetched` doesn't necessarily need to deal with `IO`, it can work for *any* monad:

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn =<< cachedOrFetched getLine getLine

cachedOrFetched :: Monad m => m String -> m String -> m String
cachedOrFetched first second = do
    cached <- first
    if not $ null cached
        then return cached
        else second
```

I would probably write

```
main :: IO ()
main = getLine >>= ifNullDo getLine >>= putStrLn

ifNullDo :: Applicative f => f String -> String -> f String
ifNullDo fetch cached = 
    if not $ null cached
        then pure cached
        else fetch
```

---

> I am not using any other imperative programming, right?

Yes you are. If you are writing a `main` function or use the `IO` type, you are writing an imperative program, one IO action after the other. The (pure) program needs to control when, if, and in what order to run the `putStrLn` and `getLine` commands.

Haskell just makes imperative programming explicit, and allows to abstract from it very easily, e.g. running a simulation instead of actual IO by swapping out the monad.

> I'd like a Haskell way, a pure way.

The Haskell way is to separate the pure application logic from the impure boundary to the outside world; very much like the [ports and adapters architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)). Of course, this can only go so far, and for a toy example such as `cachedOrFetched` it's hard to see where to put the boundary. But in larger applications, you typically come up with your own abstraction for "actions" in the business logic, and deal only with them instead of `IO` directly.

Comment: This seems very interesting - use `Applicative` to avoid `IO`, a more abstracted way! Do you think `ifNullDo` can be still considered as a pure function?

Comment: `IO` itself isn't impure. For example, `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` is a pure function: give a string, it always returns the same `IO ()` value. The impurity comes from the *execution* of that `IO` value by the Haskell runtime.

Answer (score 3):

This is what your code looks like when written in [`do` notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation):

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  cached <- getLine
  fetched <- getLine
  putStrLn $ cachedOrFetched cached fetched
```

You can see that both IO actions are getting done before the call to `cachedOrFetched` is even happening. You could do everything in `main` like so:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do
  cached <- getLine
  if not $ null cached
    then putStrLn cached
    else do
      fetched <- getLine
      putStrLn fetched
```

The reason is because `cachedOrFetched` *must have access to both values* (they are arguments to its call!) before being able to make a decision about which to choose.