# Haskell Combining non-determinism with error handling

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, non-deterministic

Suppose I'm creating a simple interpreter that can throw errors, e.g.

```
type Error = String

data Term = Con Int | Div Term Term

eval :: (MonadError Error m) => Term -> m Int
eval (Con a) = return a
eval (Div u v) = do
  a <- eval u
  b <- eval v
  if b == 0 then
    throwError "Division by zero"
  else
    return $ a `div` b
```

A typical choice of a concrete error handler, would be `Either Error`.

```
runEval :: Term -> Either Error Int
runEval = eval
```

Suppose now that I want to extend this interpreter to handle non-determinism. For example, I can add a term `Choice Term Term` that can either evaluate to its first or second argument.

```
data Term = Con Int | Div Term Term | Choice Term Term
```

I could then represent a concrete evaluation as `[Either Error Int]`, where each item in the list represents a possible evaluation. However, I'm struggling how I can add the `Choice` case to my `eval` function without modifying the `Con` and `Div` cases.

## What I tried:

```
eval :: (MonadError Error m, MonadPlus m) => Term -> m Int
-- The Con and Div cases remain unchanged.
eval (Choice u v) = do
  w <- return u `mplus` return v  -- pick either u or v
  eval w

runEval :: Term -> [Either Error Int]
runEval = runExceptT . eval
```

However, this only returns the first possible outcome, and doesn't backtrack.

```
> let t = Con 1 `Div` (Choice (Con 0) (Con 1))
> runEval t
[Left "Division by zero"]
```

What I expected: `[Left "Division by zero", Right 1]`.

What is the right way to combine non-determinism and error-handling?

Comment: You can take a look at *monad transformers*. This is more or less used to create a "stack" of monad contexts.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for the remark. Indeed, the goal would be to combine the error monad and the list monad using a transformer. That's actually what I do in `runEval`: there I use `runExceptT` which I think means that Haskell will effectively use the monad `ExceptT Error [] Int` for my computation. However, as my question explains, it doesn't work as I would expect.

Comment: Currently, your `eval` does `ExceptT Error [] Int`, but what you want is `ListT (ExceptT Error) Int`, I think.

Comment: @ArtemPelenitsyn With `ListT (ExceptT Error)` a single error would stop the computation. `runEval` would have a signature like `Term -> Either Error [Int]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root of the problem is the `MonadPlus` instance for [`ExceptT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Except.html#t:ExceptT).

```
(Monad m, Monoid e) => MonadPlus (ExceptT e m)
```

It doesn't piggyback on a `MonadPlus` instance of the base monad `m`. Instead of that, it requires a `Monoid` instance from the error `e`.

And `mplus` doesn't return the collection of all failures and successes. Instead of that, it returns either the *first* success or the monoidal combination of all the failures:

```
ghci> throwError ['a'] `mplus` throwError ['b'] :: Except String ()
ExceptT (Identity (Left "ab"))
ghci> throwError ['a'] `mplus` throwError ['b'] `mplus` return () :: Except String ()
ExceptT (Identity (Right ()))
ghci> return 'a' `mplus` return 'b' :: ExceptT () [] Char
ExceptT [Right 'a']
```

What we could try is to define our own monad having the `MonadPlus` instance we want (while reusing all other instances from `ExceptT` through `deriving`, to avoid boilerplate).

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Control.Monad.Except

newtype OopsT e m a = OopsT { runOopsT :: ExceptT e m a }
    deriving stock (Show)
    deriving newtype (Show,Functor,Applicative,Monad,MonadError e,MonadTrans)

-- We delegate on the Alternative/Monadplus instance of the base monad m
instance MonadPlus m => Alternative (OopsT e m) where
    empty = OopsT (ExceptT empty)       
    OopsT (ExceptT xs) <|> OopsT (ExceptT ys) = OopsT (ExceptT (xs <|> ys)

instance MonadPlus m => MonadPlus (OopsT e m) where
    mzero = empty       
    mplus = (<|>)

runEval :: Term -> [Either Error Int]
runEval = runExceptT . runOopsT . eval
```

Now it seems to work as intended:

```
ghci> let t = Con 1 `Div` (Choice (Con 0) (Con 1))
ghci> runEval t
[Left "Division by zero",Right 1]
```

---

One potentially troubling aspect of the `MonadPlus` instance for `OopsT` is that it doesn't seem to satisfy the `v >> mzero   =  mzero` law mentioned in the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:mzero). For example:

```
ghci> (mzero :: OopsT Char [] Int)
OopsT {runOopsT = ExceptT []}
ghci> throwError 'c' >> (mzero :: OopsT Char [] Int)
OopsT {runOopsT = ExceptT [Left 'c']}
```

Perhaps we could use the equivalent `Alternative` instance instead, which doesn't seem to require that law?

Comment: Nice explanation. Can I ask: what is the intended full form of `Oops`?

Comment: @Safron I'm not sure what you mean by "full form". `Oops` is an example of a common pattern: an auxiliary newtype on which we selectively derive or define instances. We have derived a lot of useful instances (from `Functor` to `MonadTrans`) from the underlying type, which saved us work, and had to define  two instances  by hand (`Alternative` and `MonadPlus`) to suit our needs.

Comment: Right, I was thinking it was some kind of abbrevation, but now I see that it probably is just meant as a synonym for "something that can fail" aka "oops". My bad :-)

Comment: A question: what is the outcome of `runEval $ Div (Div (Con 1) (Con 0)) (Choice (Con 1) (Con 2))`? Is there one or two errors in the result? (A lawful instance should have 2)

Comment: @Jesper It returns only one error `[Left "Division by zero"]`. According to what law should it return 2?

Comment: I was working under the assumption of some distribution law `a >> (b <|> c) == (a >> b) <|> (a >> c)`. But now I can't find it in the laws for `MonadPlus`, so maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @Jesper No, it doesn't seem to be distributive: `(throwError 'c' :: OopsT Char [] Int) >> (pure 2 <|> pure 3)` is different from `((throwError 'c' :: OopsT Char [] Int) >> pure 2) <|> (throwError 'c' >> pure 3)`. It doesn't satisfy `v >> mzero   =  mzero` either. Perhaps, instead of defining a not-very-lawful `MonadPlus` instance, the best approach could be to work with a concrete `ExceptT Error []` stack and lift list operations as needed without committing to those laws, as defining a `MonadPlus` instance seems to do.

Comment: Indeed, maybe the most general solution would be to replace the `MonadPlus m` constraint with `Alternative m`, then get rid of the unlawful `MonadPlus` instance and replace ``w <- return u `mplus` return v`` with ``w <- pure u <|> pure v``.

Comment: A related SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167879/distinction-between-typeclasses-monadplus-alternative-and-monoid and an entry from the Haskell Wikibook discussing `Alternative` and `MonadPlus` https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Alternative_and_MonadPlus